# JAsper Report 3.0 issue :

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using jasper Reoprt Ireport 3.0 for Generating excel. my problem is I have One text field in that i want to keep below data which is coming from my database.

```
**Disclaimer: Please note that in case of disease conditions which can have both Acute and Chronic manifestations, they are considered as Chronic illness for analysis keeping in view the objective of the report.
```

Actually in jasper reoprt summary area i have given one text field but it is too small too keep this above line data. but still I want to keep whole data in small field in excel . 
because normaly when we are typing in excel cell anything and when it become overflows then also it's looking like it has been typed in next cell but ,when we are clicking in another cell it will show in that cell only.whole data will come in that small cell without wrapping text filed.

just like it i want also through I-report 3.0 . I tried so much but I didn't find solution so i am posting here . please suggest if you faced same problem and got solution too. it will be helpful.

I don't want to merge it in multiple columns because if it will merge multiple columns then for calculating value through Excel column selection will be a problem. and V lookup we cant do so.

if the data in any cell is greater than 2 rows, then the remaining data just gets cut off and not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is time to update. At this time JasperReports 6.x is the version to go, but ...

From my expierience **JasperReports** is the wrong tool to generate "clean" Excel documents. You get always layout informations in it that result in the behaviour you describe.

To get a clean Excel document I would suggest to go with **Apache-Poi** (https://poi.apache.org/) and generate it directly or simply to generate a **CSV** - file which can be easily opened using Excel.